Azure B2C Home Realm Discovery Custom Policy
Our Azure tenant supports multiple UPN suffixes.  For example:  Within the same tenant we have user accounts with first.last@company.com, first.last@company.client.com, first.last@jv.com...We have about 15 UPN suffixes.
I have Home Realm Discovery functioning with first.last@company.com but cannot figure out how to code the custom policy so that first.last@company.client.com and first.last@jv.com utilize the same ClaimsProvider (IDP) that first.last@company.com is directed to.
I have tried to duplicate the ClaimsProvider for each UPD suffix but the xlm files fail to upload.

Slightly confused here.
If you want "first.last@company.client.com and first.last@jv.com to utilize the same ClaimsProvider (IDP) that first.last@company.com is directed to", there is no HRD.
This is exactly the same as one tenant allowing both joe@hotmail.com and joe@gmail.com.
HRD is where you want joe@company.com and joe@institute.com to use different IDP.
